# Connecting Lambda to both RDS and S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vpc

I have a Node.js task that converts values from my database to MP3 files, then uploads them to s3 storage. The code works beautifully when executing it on my laptop. I decided to migrate it to Lambda so I can run it automatically every couple hours. I made a few minor modifications, and again, it works great. But here's the catch: it's only working when my RDS instance is set to allow connections from ANY IP. Obviously, that's an unacceptable security risk.

I put my database and Lambda code in the same VPC and security group, but even so, my code wouldn't connect to S3. Then, I added an endpoint for S3, and it looked like everything was working per my console logs. However, the file in S3 storage is empty (0 bytes).

What do I need to change? I've heard that I might need to configure my VPC to have internet access, but I'm not sure if that's what I need to do. And honestly, those tutorials seem confusing to me.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Assuming you Lambda function and RDS instance are in the same VPC, you don't need a VPC NAT Gateway to access either RDS or S3. You only need to (1) setup a [VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html) for S3 with proper endpoint policy access to S3 and (2) configure the security group for your RDS instance to allow inbound traffic from you Lambda's security group. You shouldn't allow connections from any IP to your RDS instance.

Comment: @khalid I tried this, but my uploaded files in s3 come through  empty (0 bytes). This is not a problem when testing with open ip permissions. Any idea why?

Comment: Based on your remarks, I just can't think of anything other than a misconfiguration in the RDS security group. Would you be able to edit the question to show the current security group inbound rules for your RDS instance?

Comment: I will post the security settings shortly when I have access to my computer. But I'm pretty sure that's not the problem. I have programmed the file name to correspond to the database value, and that's working. I can also see the database value in my lambda console logs. So it seems I'm successfully reaching both rds and s3, but my file is simply empty when using a vpc in lambda with  an endpoint.

Comment: I think I figured out what the problem is. My code is designed to send text  from my database value to Amazon Polly for conversion to MP3. When I enter the VPC, my guess is that internet access to that service is terminated. And because no contact is made with Amazon Polly, the resulting file is 0 bytes. Am I correct that the only way to access both Amazon Polly and S3 and RDS would be to use a NAT?

Comment: Correct. You'll need a NAT instance inside VPC.

Answer (score -2):

It is a known problem (known by users, not really acknowledged by AWS that I've seen) The lambda vps docs say:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html

> "When a Lambda function is configured to run within a VPC, it incurs
>   an additional ENI start-up penalty. This means address resolution may
>   be delayed when trying to connect to network resources."

And

> "If your Lambda function accesses a VPC, you must make sure that your
>   VPC has sufficient ENI capacity to support the scale requirements of
>   your Lambda function. "

Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=767285

This means it has serious drawbacks that make it unworkable:

1. speed penalty
2. have to manually setup scaling
3. have to pay for NAT gateway 0.059 per hour (https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/)